# bash script if statement

Tags: bash, shell

I made a script to check tnsping but the if statement does not working properly. The following is the script:

```
ping=$(tnsping oracle1 |grep OK| awk -F" " '{print $1 }')

if [ -n $ping ]
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NOT OK"
fi
```

If a execute change oracle for a non-existing oracle server I also receive "OK".

-n = The length of STRING is greater than zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap double quotes around `$ping`:

```
if [ -n "$ping" ]
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NOT OK"
fi
```

Or it will undergo word splitting and globbing and resolve in the following arguments for `[`: `'-n'` and `']'` when `$ping` is empty. which is the same as:

```
 if [ '-n' '-n' ']'
```

See [`man test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> **-n** STRING
>   the length of STRING is nonzero
>   **STRING
>
>   equivalent to -n STRING**
>   **-z** STRING
>   the length of STRING is zero

---

And FYI you can omit the call to `grep` and use awk directly. And since the default Field Separator (-F) is space that can be omitted as well:

```
ping=$(tnsping oracle1 | awk '/OK/{print $1 }')
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither the `$ping` *variable* nor `awk` are necessary, since `grep` can return an *exit code* to `if`:

```
if tnsping oracle1 | grep --quiet OK
then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NOT OK"
fi
```

Comment: This is correct, but that is only because awk squeezes spaces and `<space><space>OK` will put `OK` in `$1`. If OP was printing `$2` it would not be possible.

Comment: @andlrc, well-taken pointers on the value of carefulness are useful.  However, for my *non*-`awk` answer, `awk`'s behavior is irrelevant, and the OP was _not_ printing `$2`.